# Rails [AXLSX]: Change Currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I need to change the currency format on an Excel file that is exported.
The default currency pattern is US (1,000.00) [One Thousand] and I need it to become PT-BR format (1.000,00) [One Thousand].

I have tried implementing this way:

```rb
    formated = workbook.styles.add_style(format_code: '$#.##0,00')
```

but the only thing it did, was add more zeroes after the .

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO :)

Yo might try this:

```
formated = workbook.styles.add_style(:format_code => '#.###,##')
```

Comment: People use Excel in Portuguese, so it changes the currency. The resulted file is something with dots instead of commas, so formulas won't work.

Comment: It have worked now. I found that the problem of it was that somewhere in the code the type was set to string.

Comment: Nice! Glad it did :)